# How to use database adapters' cursors safely?

Tags: python, database, postgres

I started to use psycopg2 to connect my little python script to a PostgreSQL database few days ago. After some research I found that a lot of database connector, like psycopg, work using cursors.

I know what is a cursor and how to use it. But I still wonder if it's safe to use the same cursor all along the script life.

Is it safe?

Or would it be preferable to use a different cursor for each query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe creating a cursor starts a transaction in postgresql.

If that's the case (I don't know for sure) then:

- INSERTS and UPDATES would not be reflected in other sessions because of transaction isolation
- you may overflow the transaction buffer given enough commands

Comment: I find nothing about the re-usability of a cursor on the Internet. But I think you're right then. Thank you.